# Django admin change many to many label text

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have the field as part of a Room class

```
roomextra = models.ManyToManyField(
    to='hotel.RoomExtra',
    related_name='room_extra',
    verbose_name='room extra',
)
```

whereby Django has created the many to many relationship for me. This relationship is displayed as a TabularInline:

admin.py

```
class RoomExtraInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Room.roomextra.through
    extra = 1
    verbose_name = _('Customise Room Extra')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Customise Room Extra(s)')
    form = AddRoomAddRoomExtrasForm
```

In the Django admin, if I add a room extra I get the text in the image below:

[image]

```
Room_roomextra object (5)
```

above the option I have selected. How can I change the Room_roomextra string?

**Update**

Code as requested

```
class RoomExtra(models.Model):

    PER_PERSON = 0
    PER_ROOM = 1
    PER_CHOICES = [
        (PER_PERSON, _('Person')),
        (PER_ROOM, _('Room')),
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cost = models.DecimalField(
        default="0.00",
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))],
    )
    cost_per = models.IntegerField(
        choices=PER_CHOICES,
        default=PER_ROOM,
        verbose_name=_('Cost per'),
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Room(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.ForeignKey(
        to='hotel.RoomType',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    location = models.ForeignKey(
        to='hotel.Location',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        blank=True,
        max_length=500,
    )
    roomextra = models.ManyToManyField(
        to='hotel.RoomExtra',
        related_name='room_extra',
        verbose_name='room extra',
    )
    bathroom = models.ForeignKey(
        to='hotel.Bathroom',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Does `RoomExtra` model implements __str__ method?

Comment: @Charnel both Room and RoomExtra implement 'str'

Comment: And can you share that part of code?

Comment: @Charnel see update

Comment: By any chance are you using Py2?

Comment: @Charnel just figured it out using a proxy model, will post code once complete

Answer (score 1):

Adding a proxy model for Room // Room Extra allows the change of output text on the Django admin

```
class RoomRoomExtraProxy(Room.roomextra.through):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.room.name + ' // ' + self.roomextra.name
```